# Comparing live data from two websockets

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm just discovering websockets and node js but trying to figure out how to do the following. I want to compare values from two different websockets.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://1');
const w = new WebSocket('wss://2')

ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {

  var myval1= JSON.parse(data);


});

w.on('message', function incoming(data) {

  var myval2= JSON.parse(data);


});

var whatIwant =  myval1 - myval2;
```

How could I go on about comparing myva1 and myval2?

I've tried putting the second on message call inside the first one but it then starts looping every time the first one is called and breakers after a few times message is called.

Comment: How do you decide what the pairs of messages are?

Comment: This is a state dependent thing. Maybe when the first sends the message, the 2nd haven't sent any message yet, or vice-versa. You need to keep a check on all this.

Comment: @ZeekHuge My question really is how can access myval2 or myval1 outside of the on message call? So every time one of the two websockets is updated, I check the difference with the other one.

Comment: @Callombert: The variable has to be in a "larger" scope. Which, I would guess be a global variable.

Comment: @ZeekHuge Example on how to do that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While ZeekHuge is correct that we need to remember scope - we also have to take the async nature of websockets into consideration - we can only do the comparison once we have received a message. A helper method could be called each time a message is received to compare the value.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://1');
const w = new WebSocket('wss://2')

let myval1;
let myval2;

function compareValues(a, b) {
  // Do some kind of comparison here.
  if (a === b) {
    // Do a thing.
  };
}

ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  myval1= JSON.parse(data);
  compareValues(myval1, myval2);
});

w.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  myval2= JSON.parse(data);
  compareValues(myval1, myval2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to compare the variable from the 2 web-sockets, you will have to save one of the variables will have to be in a "larger" scope (at least in the given example, since there is no database involved). Using your code as an example :

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://1');
const w = new WebSocket('wss://2')

var myval1 = null;
var myval2 = null;
ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {

  myval1= JSON.parse(data);


});

w.on('message', function incoming(data) {

  myval2= JSON.parse(data);


});

var whatIwant =  myval1 - myval2;
```

Note that there are more important things to be considered in your code :

- `var whatIwant...` will be executed as soon as this script is run and it wont for the messages to arrive.

**EDIT**

To be able to compare values each time a message is received, following can be done.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://1');
const w = new WebSocket('wss://2')

var w_val = null;
var ws_val = null;
ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {

    ws_val = JSON.parse(data);
    if (w_val !== null ) {
        var comp = ws_val - w_val;
        w_val = null;
        ws_val = null;
    }


});

w.on('message', function incoming(data) {

    w_val = JSON.parse(data);
    if (ws_val !== null ) {
        var comp = ws_val - w_val;
        ws_val = null;
        w_val = null;
    }


});
```

Comment: What I'm after is a way to compare the two values every time the websocket updates, I don't think this achieves that.